# mod_rewrite add route if the file exists

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I'd like to rewrite all requests to files that exist to include a route prefix, so `/favicon.ico` becomes `/public/favicon.ico`, but only if `/favicon.ico` exists.

Is this possible? I also have rules following this one to further process the request.